# Bitbucket api set repository access roles

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I've created a repository in BitBucket using the api:

```
curl -v -X POST -d '{"scm": "git", "is_private": "true", "fork_policy": "no_forks", "project": {"key": "MARS"}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"  https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/myteam/test -u <user-name>
```

How can I set user-access roles for the new repository?
Specifically I want to set a group TeamAdmins to have admin privileges

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Bitbucket team, but maybe someone will look for this:

There is currently no support for this in api-2, and no current due date on the feature.

You can do this using API-1: using  [privileges-endpoint](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/privileges-endpoint-296093145.html)